# Selenium - Retrieve the element data- throwing error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the `span` element which has `OK` as value.

I could not get it using the code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".pull-left.value.smaller.localtime"));
System.out.println(elements.size());
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Could not find the element. Error is coming after execution. Can some one help me?
Below is my HTML code from which I am reading the value:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="custpanheader">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
               <span class="label label-default pull-left">aaaaaaaa</span>
               <br>
               <span class="label label-default pull-left">bbbbbbbbbb</span>
               <br>
               <div class="thumbnail col-xs-12" style="padding:8px;">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">ccccccccccc</span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">2015-04-10 12:09:26</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">sdfdfsdfsddfsd</span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">2016-08-08 10:59:58</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">erwerwerwerew</span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">2016-07-11 06:12:32</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">gjghjhgjghjfh</span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">2016-10-09 06:12:32</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">ghuyikhjhgh</span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">2018-04-30</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 nomargin">
                     <span class="pull-left label-b smaller">sdfdsfdzfsd</span>
                     <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg pull-right"></span>
                     <br>
                     <span class="pull-left value smaller localtime">OK</span>
                     <br>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the error coming when you're executing??

Comment: Have you looked to see whether this HTML is inside an `IFRAME`? Your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative xpath  as below for locating the element:

```
    //span[@class='pull-left value smaller localtime' AND text()='OK']
```

Hope it helps!